# Magento Add to Shopping cart Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

After installing an fresh magento in bluehost and created a simple product and tried adding to cart. But the shopping cart page shows empty

I am not getting any errors in error log. I have tried clearing cache and reindexing all the indexes.If I add a product from search page, product is adding to cart. Any help please ?

Comment: check the console log for errors

Comment: You should check permission of folders

Comment: I have already checked it.  No errors in log file.

Comment: Please check files are folder permission, seems because of that session or cookie not creating also you should correct your cookie domain that may help you. System > Config > Web > Session Cookie Management

Comment: I have checked the folder and file permissions. Everything is fine still  shopping cart shows empty.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Make sure, that your cookie domain is correct (check whether your session ID changes all the time)